# Hiding and Showing Selecboxes Using jQuery Selectmenu Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am trying to use the jQuery Selectbox plugin to create cascading selectboxes.  I have 2 selectboxes; one listing s/w (tool) and one for tool version.  I want to be able to select a tool, show the tool version selectbox and write version-specific data to the screen.  I have this working w/out using the Selectbox plugin by inserting the following into the “if (tool == "toolname") { “ section of code:

```
$("#tb select:not(#tool, #cgs)").hide();
```

But this does not seem to work w/ the Selectbox plugin.  I suspect it is due to my limited Javascript and jQuery experience.  If I could get “tool” to be global I could use it on the last line of $(document).ready(function().  Right now it only works if I hardcode the tool name into the last line:

```
$('select#toolname).selectmenu({maxHeight: 150}).parent("fieldset").hide();
```

The javascript and HTML is listed below.  Any thoughts or help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Ken

**Javascript Pastie:**
http://pastie.org/2685454

**HTML Pastie:**
http://pastie.org/2685522

Answer (score 1):

Here is the final solution and hopefully it will help someone:

**Javascript Pastie:**
http://pastie.org/2695842

Answer (score 0):

First off, your Javascript doesn't run.  You don't close the handler for `#cgs` (which is likely a mistake, since it's under the `dpss` else case.)

In the callback, you can get the real value of the select element with `this.value` - `options.value` does not seem to work.

`tool` also doesn't get defined until after you select a tool with the menu - that line should go in the `select` callback function so it doesn't get run before the variable is defined.

Comment: Dennis, thanks for your input.  I feel really stupid.  I've been making so many changes I wasn't aware I had those errors in the Javascript I posted.  The errors were not in my code but occurred when editing out extra code to make the posting clearer.  Anyway,

Comment: Dennis, thanks for your input.  I feel really stupid.  I've been making so many changes I wasn't aware I had those errors in the Javascript I posted.  The errors were not in my code but occurred when editing out extra code to make the posting clearer.  Anyway,

Comment: Not sure how to make a line break here but apparently "enter" is not the way?  I will post my solution below in case anyone is interested.